# Proof of the optional sampling theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, martingales

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\operatorname{P})$ be a probability space
- $\mathbb{F}$ be a Filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a nonnegative $\mathbb{F}$-supermartingale
- $\tau$ be a $\mathbb{F}$ stopping time and $\operatorname{P}$-almost surely $\tau<\infty$

Moreover, let $$X_\tau(\omega):=X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)\;\;\;\text{for all}\; \omega\in\Omega$$ and $$\tau\wedge n:=\min\left\{\tau,n\right\}\;\;\;\text{for all}\;n\in\mathbb{N}_0$$

I want to prove $$\operatorname{E}\left[X_\tau\right]\le \operatorname{E}\left[X_0\right]<\infty$$

---

**My ideas:**

- $\operatorname{P}\left[\tau<\infty\right]=1\Rightarrow\operatorname{P}$-almost surely there is a $T\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\tau\le T$
- So, we've got for $\operatorname{P}$-almost every $\omega\in\Omega$ $$\left|X_{\tau(\omega)\wedge n}-X_{\tau(\omega)}\right|=0\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge T$$ and thereby $\operatorname{P}$-almost surely $$\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{\tau\wedge n}=X_\tau$$
- Additionaly, we've got $\operatorname{P}$-almost surely $\tau\wedge n\le T$ and thereby $$\operatorname{E}\left[X_{\tau\wedge n}\right]\le\operatorname{E}\left[X_0\right]$$ (which can be easily proven)
- Since $X_\tau\ge 0$ and $\operatorname{P}$-almost everywhere $$X_\tau\le\max_{0\le n\le T}X_n\in\mathcal{L}^1(\operatorname{P})$$
- Thus, by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem and the lemma of Fatou, we've got $$\operatorname{E}\left[X_\tau\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{\tau\wedge n}\right]\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{E}\left[X_{\tau\wedge n}\right]\le\operatorname{E}\left[X_0\right]<\infty$$

Is this a correct proof? If not, can you explain to me what I did wrong and come up with a correct proof?

Comment: Your statement of the theorem is wrong. $\tau$ must be almost surely *bounded*, not almost surely finite. If $\tau<\infty$ a.s. this does **not** mean there must exist a $K$ such that $\tau \leq K$. $\tau$ being the first hitting time of $1$ for a Brownian motion is a good demonstrative example of this.

Comment: @TyrCurtis Perfect! That means that something is wrong with my *proof*. But the *statement* itself, is true.

Comment: No, the statement is wrong. You say "let $\tau<\infty$ a.s.". What you should be saying is "let $\tau < K$ for some $K>0$ a.s.

Comment: @TyrCurtis I agree with you, that if $\tau$ is almost surely bounded, the statement is proven by my proof. But all we need is $\tau<\infty$ almost surely. Otherwise: Can you prove that $X_{\tau\wedge n}\to X_\tau$ almost surely, doesn't need to hold?

Comment: By assumption, we have that $$1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}\left|X_{\tau\wedge n}-X_\tau\right|=1_{\left\{\tau<\infty\right\}}1_{\left\{\tau>n\right\}}\left|X_n-X_\tau\right|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$$ Thus, $$X_{\tau\wedge n}\stackrel{\text{almost surely}}{\to}X_\tau$$ Meanwhile, I don't think that we need dominated convergence, since $$\operatorname{E}\left[X_{\tau} \right]=\operatorname{E}\left[\color{blue}{1_{\left\{\displaystyle\limsup_{n \to\infty}\left|X_{\tau\wedge n}-X_\tau\right| =0\right\}}}X_{\tau}\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[\liminf_{n \to\infty}X_{\tau\wedge n}\right]$$

Comment: Yes, my apologies you are right. I didn't read very carefully. You are proving an inequality for positive supermartingales; I thought you were trying to prove the *equality* version of OST for martingales.

Comment: @TyrCurtis There is more than *one* OST. Besides, the statement that you mean can even be proven for infinite stopping times. The only additional restriction to the (super-)martingal you need is uniform integrability.